# Rerun an extensions SQL files

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, sql

Whats the best way to rerun an extensions SQL files for example

mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
mysql4-install-0.1.1.php
mysql4-install-0.1.2.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the record from the `core_resource` table where `code` matches your extension name.
Clear the cache when you are done.
Then just refresh any page.